# How to get the latest uploaded file on Filestore in Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

In this directory there are multiple parquet files I am checking through a magic commands

```
%sh ls -lth /dbfs/mnt/sgi/report/descriptive/granular_market_size
```

As you can see on image i want to get only those files which uploaded on 15 march only.
[image]

Can you please tell me how to filter the latest uploaded files. I have to store them on a subfolder.

I have used `%sh find  /dbfs/mnt/sgi/report/descriptive/granular_market_size -mtime -1` but not getting any output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
%sh
find /dbfs/FileStore -mtime -1
```

Reference: [man find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). `-mtime -1` makes it find files modified less than a day ago.

Comment: Actually I want to store the results and create a directory and move them into it. But this magic command i can't store it into the variable

Comment: Like [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/168164/move-files-into-one-directory-in-linux-with-find/)?

Comment: I edit the question can you pls look into this

Answer (score 0):

- To get the files modified on March 15th, you can use the following procedure. Let's say I have the following file content in my storage directory.

```
%sh ls -lth /dbfs/FileStore
```

[image]

- Now, I have files modified/created on March 16th. So, if I want to get the files modified on this date, I can use the following command:

```
%sh find /dbfs/FileStore -type f -newermt "2023-03-16 00:00:00" ! -newermt "2023-03-17 00:00:00"
```

[image]

- If you want to filenames based on creation date, try using the following command. Change the dates as per requirement:

```
%sh find /dbfs/FileStore -type f -newermt "2023-03-16 00:00:00" ! -newermt "2023-03-17 00:00:00" -exec stat -c %n {} \;
```

[image]